# Print 5 Chinese Fortunes 1 at a time randomly from a list, input yes, print another fortune from the list without repetition

Tags: python, list, random, while-loop, sample

I am trying to make a python program that prints 5 different chinese fortune cookie fortunes from a list. It will print one the ask "Would you like another fortune?" User replies yes, then it prints another fortune randomly selected from the list, until all five have been printed.

My issue is I do not know how to write the code so that there are no repetitions from the list.

I am very new to python, like 60 pages into the book I'm reading new.

```
import random 

fortunes_list = ['Good fortunes to you', 'chinese stuff', 'the sauce is the sauce', 'too much sauce can be a bad thing',
'if its some gang, its some gang']


sampled_fortunes = random.sample(fortunes_list, 1)

print(sampled_fortunes) 

input("do you want another fortune?")

answer = ""

while answer != "no":
    print(sampled_fortunes)
    input("do you want another fortune?")
```

```
import random 

fortunes_list = ['Good fortunes to you', 'chinese stuff', 'the sauce is the sauce', 'too much sauce can be a bad thing',
'if its some gang, its some gang']

print(random.choice(fortunes_list)) 

input("do you want another fortune?")

answer = ""

while answer != "no":
    print(random.choice(fortunes_list))
    input("do you want another fortune?")
```

Comment: does ```fortunes_list``` always contain 5 quotes? If yes, why don't you just print all of them one by one using for loop until user enter "no". If no, then you can create a ```set``` to keep track of the index of the quote that you already presented to user. And while generating random int, check if the index in ```set```. If yes, generate another random int, if not print the quote from the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pop() method. It removes an element from list and returns it. If you want to keep original list you will have to make a copy.

```
import random

fortunes_list = ['Good fortunes to you', 'chinese stuff', 'the sauce is the sauce', 'too much sauce can be a bad thing',
'if its some gang, its some gang']

working_list = fortunes_list.copy()

answer = input("do you want another fortune?")

while answer != "no" and len(working_list) > 0:
    sampled_fortunes = random.choice(range(len(working_list)))
    print(working_list.pop(sampled_fortunes))
    input("do you want anothehr fortune?")

print("Fortunes exhausted")
```

Note that I have not included any code to check for responses other than "no" but you should in order to make the program more robust and user friendly.